# Logical reason when cast an object to object type in Equals method

Tags: c#

When refreshing my knowledge about Equals in C#, I found below code in MSDN
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx 
and wonder if there is any logical reason to cast an object to object type before comparing to null like below:

```
public bool Equals(TwoDPoint p)
{
    // If parameter is null return false:
    if ((object)p == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Return true if the fields match:
    return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
}
```

What is the difference between p == null and (object) p == null in the context?